# Empty array is being returned

Tags: solidity, quorum

Am trying to add few hashes into an array and retrieve those but the getHash() is returning an empty array. My smart contract is :

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract simpleexample{

bytes32 public inputHash;
bytes32[] inputHashArray;

function addNewHash(bytes32 input) public {
  inputHash = input;
  inputHashArray.push(inputHash)-1;
  return;
}

function getHash() view public returns (bytes32[] memory){
  return inputHashArray;
}

function getLength() view public returns (uint) {
  return inputHashArray.length;
}

function blockTime() view public returns (uint blkTime) {
  return block.number;
}
}
```

Am sending the transaction as :

```
var simpleContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var simple =    simpleContract.new(0x37cfa6a8721ac72e8472dbcc55ec7bc773730de36217504c3addc9e93480443e, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: bytecode, gas: 0x47b760, privateFor: ["ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="]}, function(e, contract) {
    if (e) {
            console.log("err creating contract", e);
    } else {
            if (!contract.address) {
                    console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
            } else {
                    console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
                    console.log(contract);
            }
    }
    });
```

Any clue as to what am missing?

Comment: What is this code??? Function `addNewHash` takes input argument named `input`, but doesn't do anything with it. It then refers to a symbol named `manifestHash` which is not declared anywhere in the contract. Finally, there is that `-1` appearing after the `push` statement, which only the goddess of enigmas knows why it is there. If you actually expect anyone to take you seriously, then you should make some effort to reach a minimum standard of quality in your question!

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry, it was actually a typo. I was trying not to use the same variables which I have used in my code and hence made some mistakes while asking the question. I have updated the code with the correct variable names. Also I thought that since push gives the length of the array so -1 would go and push the element to the end of the array considering its a 0 index array. I am very new to ethereum, so please bear with me.

Comment: `push` returns the new length, `-1` would therefore yield an expression equal to the old length. But you're not saving the result of this expression to any variable, so it has no effect whatsoever. It's like writing a line of code `x-y;` or `2-1;`.

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration , that clarifies the notion of 'push'.

Comment: @goodvibration : Any clue how I could get my getHash() function return the entire array instead of an empty array?

Comment: If my answer helped you make sure to mark it as completed.

Answer (score 5):

I hope I understand you question correctly. This is the code I came up with. It is tested and should be working as expected (at least in my opinion).

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract simpleexample{
    bytes32[] inputHashArray;

    function addNewHash(bytes32 input) public returns (uint) {
      inputHashArray.push(input);
      return inputHashArray.length-1;
    }

    function getHash() view public returns (bytes32[] memory){
      return inputHashArray;
    }

    function getLength() view public returns (uint) {
      return inputHashArray.length;
    }

    function blockTime() view public returns (uint blkTime) {
      return block.number;
    }
}
```

Edit: I always get my contract like this. (This gets a smartContract not creating one!)

```
const smartContractObj= await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface), _smartContractAddress);
```

Note that the interface is the ABI.

Send a tx to smartContract like:

```
var myFunction = async () => {
    // Send the Transaction
    const result = await smartContractObj.methods
        .methodToCall(parameter1, parameter2)
        .send( { gas: '5000000', from:masterAccount });

    console.log("Transaction sent"); 
}
```

You need to use the function, because I am using async await.

Call non-state changing function on smartContract:

```
var getCart = async (_smartContractAddress, _cartID) => {
          const result = await smartContractObj.methods.methodToCall(parameter1)
          .call({from:masterAccount});

          console.log("Something fetched");

          return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Pave. So the way I check the state of the contract, I do this :
var address = "0x1932c48b2bf8102ba33b4a6b545c32236e342f34"; //where I replace this with my contract address
> var abi = [I put the contract abi here];
> var private = eth.contract(abi).at(address)

And when I check the length of the array by doing private.getLength() it still returns 0 and private.getHash() gives an empty array like this [].

Comment: @Rakri I completely updated my answer. I hope it now helps you.

Comment: I am using web3js v0.20.1 and keywords like const and new doesn't seem to work and is giving an error like - '(anonymous): Line 1:1 Unexpected reserved word' and '(anonymous): Line 1:29 Unexpected token new'.

Comment: You put the code in the async function like I sent right?

Comment: Yeah I did. So I am using this :
`> var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
undefined
> var contractInstance = MyContract.at(address);
undefined
> a = eth.accounts[0]
"0xb3b3261d10ae1eb182e9ca42446407cb4d6677c5"
> var myFunction = async () => {
... const result = await contractInstance.methods.addNewHash('0x37cfa6a8721ac72e8472dbcc55ec7bc773730de36217504c3addc9e93480443e').send({gas: '5000000', from:web3.eth.accounts[0]});
... console.log("Transaction sent");
... }
`
But I am getting this error - (anonymous): Line 1:18 Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

Comment: You are using a node.js javascript file right. Then you execute it with command 'node myjsfile.js'?

Comment: Yeah its a node.js javascript file. But I am running the ethereum node inside a docker container. So the way I execute the file is 
by using loadscript('examples/private-contract.js').